# MySQL Server Has Gone Away (MariaDB - MEMORY Engine)

Tags: mariadb, crash, mysqli

I have an OpenCart website with a bunch of plugins with encrypted files. As I added more and more products (150k currently) it became slower & slower. Since I cannot change the queries (files are encrypted) I had to change some of my tables' storage engine to MEMORY. My query times went from 50 seconds to 2 seconds.

But there is a new problem. If I try to open 4 or 5 pages at the same time DB server crashes. This is a managed VPS so I don't have access to everything. Hosting's support isn't helping at all and telling me not to use MEMORY as it is uncompatible!

I have the exact same setup on my localhost (only difference is that webhost is MariaDB but I use MySQL on my localhost) and I cannot reproduce the error on it how hard I try.

Here is the error log from within OpenCart:

```
2018-04-26 22:32:42 - PHP Warning:  mysqli::query(): MySQL server has gone away in /home/grdrop/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 18
2018-04-26 22:32:42 - PHP Warning:  mysqli::query(): Error reading result set's header in /home/grdrop/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 18
2018-04-26 22:32:42 - PHP Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=26733 in /home/grdrop/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 18
2018-04-26 22:32:42 - PHP Warning:  mysqli::query(): (00000/0):  in /home/grdrop/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 18
2018-04-26 22:32:42 - PHP Warning:  mysqli::query(): MySQL server has gone away in /home/grdrop/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 18
2018-04-26 22:32:42 - PHP Warning:  mysqli::query(): Error reading result set's header in /home/grdrop/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 18
2018-04-26 22:32:42 - PHP Warning:  mysqli::query(): MySQL server has gone away in /home/grdrop/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 18
2018-04-26 22:32:42 - PHP Warning:  mysqli::query(): Error reading result set's header in /home/grdrop/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 18
2018-04-26 22:32:42 - PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/grdrop/public_html/catalog/model/extension/module/yumenu.php on line 163
2018-04-26 22:32:42 - PHP Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=26732 in /home/grdrop/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 18
2018-04-26 22:32:42 - PHP Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=26718 in /home/grdrop/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 18
2018-04-26 22:32:42 - PHP Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=26722 in /home/grdrop/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 18
2018-04-26 22:32:42 - PHP Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=26730 in /home/grdrop/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 18
2018-04-26 22:32:42 - PHP Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=26725 in /home/grdrop/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 18
2018-04-26 22:32:42 - PHP Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=26726 in /home/grdrop/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 18
2018-04-26 22:32:43 - PHP Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=26734 in /home/grdrop/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 18
2018-04-26 22:32:43 - PHP Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=26724 in /home/grdrop/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 18
2018-04-26 22:32:43 - PHP Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=26727 in /home/grdrop/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 18
2018-04-26 22:32:44 - PHP Warning:  mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in /home/grdrop/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 7
2018-04-26 22:32:44 - PHP Warning:  DB\MySQLi::__construct(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/grdrop/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 10
2018-04-26 22:32:44 - PHP Warning:  DB\MySQLi::__construct(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/grdrop/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 10
2018-04-26 22:32:44 - PHP Warning:  mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in /home/grdrop/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 7
2018-04-26 22:32:44 - PHP Warning:  DB\MySQLi::__construct(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/grdrop/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 10
2018-04-26 22:32:44 - PHP Warning:  DB\MySQLi::__construct(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/grdrop/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 10
2018-04-26 22:32:45 - PHP Warning:  mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in /home/grdrop/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 7
2018-04-26 22:32:45 - PHP Warning:  DB\MySQLi::__construct(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/grdrop/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 10
2018-04-26 22:32:45 - PHP Warning:  DB\MySQLi::__construct(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/grdrop/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 10
2018-04-26 22:32:45 - PHP Warning:  mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in /home/grdrop/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 7
2018-04-26 22:32:45 - PHP Warning:  DB\MySQLi::__construct(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/grdrop/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 10
2018-04-26 22:32:45 - PHP Warning:  DB\MySQLi::__construct(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/grdrop/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 10
2018-04-26 22:32:45 - PHP Warning:  mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in /home/grdrop/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 7
```

I don't know much about DBs & I am completely lost here. If this is memory related issue isn't there a variable or setting that I can change so that DB waits until the first queries to finish & continue when there is enough RAM ?

Comment: It sounds like you don't have a lot of options with your current hosting solution. There may be PHP settings as well as MariaDB settings you could try, but it's unclear from your question whether you can change many of these. What version of MariaDB is this? Can you modify MariaDB option files (.cnf files)? Can you modify PHP config files? Can you restart MariDB?

Comment: @dbdemon MariaDB Version is "10.1.32-MariaDB".
I can't change them myself, but I can make the support team to change them for me and restart the server.

Comment: Please post your /etc/my.cnf + any included .cnf files in there such as /etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf or equivalent on your particular OS. Also, how much RAM do you have? Are you running a web server on the same VPS?

Comment: "it became slower & slower" -- what is "it"??  It sounds like a missing `INDEX` on the table, but I can't help you without tackling "it".